# Read csv file by using pandas and change it to array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, csv

I read csv file by using pandas. Like this

```
data = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
```

And the data looks like this.

[image: fer2013.csv]

I have to change pixels columns to array.

```
train_data = data.pixels.str.split(" ").tolist()
```

So I run this code, but this code never end. It kept running.

How to change pixels part to array(python list)?

Comment: What led you to believe that it wasn't still working? How big is your dataframe?

Comment: Because the data is not large and I've been waiting for about 15 minutes, but the process is not over.

Comment: Can you say the size at least? How many pixels and how many rows

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')

# Convert the DataFrame to a list of arrays
data_list = df.values.tolist()
```